# Problem with XeTeX normalization and \char

Tags: xetex, unicode, accents

Is there any way in Xe(La)TeX to enter a unicode character by its code, but still have XeTeX perform normalization on the resulting string of characters?

For example, the following code does not give me a PDF with \u1F05 (ἅ), which would be my desired output (and is the character this sequence should normalize to), but instead gives me still a sequence with combining characters.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Galatia SIL}

% [0: off; 1: NFC; 2: NFD]
\XeTeXinputnormalization=1

\begin{document}
α\char"0314\char"0301
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAICT, the PDF resulting from your example contains the composed U+1F05. What makes you think this is not the case?

Comment: You are right. Updating my MiKTeX installation resolved the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved by a software update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating MiKTeX, the problem was resolved and the code produced the expected U+1F05.